# Problemas al devolver respuesta desde el servlet con FETCH API a JSP

Tags: javascript, java, fetch

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial de FETCH API pero en dicho video lo estan realizando con PHP y yo lo quiero implementar en JAVA EE.

**SCRIPT DEL TUTORIAL**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CONTROLADOR TUTORIAL**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema que quiero imprimir en la consola el resultado o al menos si fue un exito o fracazo, para ir validando de que funciona correctamente, antes de implementarlo con la Base de Datos.

Se me cae la aplicación cuando en el SERVLET llego al GSON no se si deberia trabajar normal o no ya que debugeando llega al if y luego salta al catch.

**SCRIPT MIO CON JAVA**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var formulario = document.getElementById('formularioAddMarca');
            formulario.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
                e.preventDefault(); //Evita procesar el formulario
                console.log('Me tocaste pervertido');

                //Detectar inputs
                var datos = new FormData(formulario);

                //console.log(datos); //Verificar que traiga datos el formulario.
                //console.log(datos.get('marca')); //Muestra lo que el usuairo escribio en el input.

                fetch('../../marcas?bt=addMarca',{
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: datos,
                    headers:{
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })

                //Promesas (repsuestas)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then( data => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    Swal.fire(
                        'Good job!',
                        'You clicked the button!',
                        'success'
                    )
                })
                .catch(function(error){
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Oops...',
                        text: 'Something went wrong!',
                      })
                });
            })
        </script>
```

**SERVLET**

```
try {
            String nombreMarca = request.getParameter("marca");

            Gson gson = new Gson();

            if (nombreMarca.isEmpty() ) {
                JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree("No puede estar vacio");
            element.toString();
            }else{
                JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(nombreMarca);
                element.toString();
            }

            response.sendRedirect("view/marca/marcas.jsp");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            request.setAttribute("mjeError", "Error al registrar la marca");
            response.sendRedirect("view/marca/marcas.jsp");
        }
```

No entra nisiquiera al if o esta mal realizado la respuesta del servlet no se, primera vez que utilizo FETCH API con JS. Y de lo que obtengo en la consola es solo respuesta de error con esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**FORMULARIO AGREGAR**

```
            <!-- MODAL AGREGAR -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="agregarModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
                 aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Agregar nuevo Marca</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <form id="formularioAddMarca">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <label for="marca" class="form-control-label">Nombre Marca</label>
                                <input type="text" name="marca" id="marca" class="form-control"  maxlength="20">
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- FIN MODAL AGREGAR -->
```

Comment: La variable formulario presenta problemas, agrega tu HTML

Comment: @BetaM listo hay agregue el HTML, pero si tengo un console y si me toma la variable. Aqui en el JS deje comentado donde me muestra la variable del formulario.

Comment: @BetaM Logre que llegara al servlet ahora me faltaba colocar ../../marcas?bt=addMarca, ahora el problema se me cae cuando llego al IF y salta al CATCH osea la excepción.

Comment: @AlexValenzuela si ya resolviste este problema te recomienod hacer otra pregunta para el otro problema que tienes. Saludos.